# Changing autocomplete in Sublime Text to use single quotes instead of double quotes (HTML)

Tags: html, sublimetext

By default sublime text autocomplete uses double quotes, for example if I start typing

```
<img
```

and hit tab, it will suggest:

```
<img src="">
```

Is it possible to change the autocomplete behaviour so that it suggests:

```
<img src=''>
```

and similarly for other elements, for example:

```
<a href=''></a>
```

i.e. I'm looking for a global solution, not to change the behaviour one autocomplete at a time.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible globally. Different [packages](https://github.com/sublimehq/Packages) use different methods for generating [completions](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/completions.html): [`.sublime-completion` files](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/completions.html#completion_files), [snippets](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/completions.html#snippets), and Python-based [plugins](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/completions.html#plugins). Some of them do use single quotes, for example the Python [`if __name__ == '__main__'` snippet](https://github.com/sublimehq/Packages/blob/master/Python/Snippets/if-__name__-%3D%3D-%27__main__%27.sublime-snippet), but others, like [`html_completions.py`](https://github.com/sublimehq/Packages/blob/master/HTML/html_completions.py), use double quotes.

If you use one or a few languages primarily, it might be possible to edit the completions files to your liking using a tool like [`PackageResourceViewer`](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/PackageResourceViewer), but there isn't a way to do it globally.